# How to detect when nth image within a div (image slider) is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image slider like this:

```
<div class="outer_wrapper_hide" id="outer_wrapperID">
    <div class="inner_wrapper" id="inner_wrapperID">
        <img id="slideimage1" class="slideimage" height="500" width="500" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Svg_example_square.svg/500px-Svg_example_square.svg.png" alt="Green Square">
        <img id="slideimage2" class="slideimage" height="500" width="500" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/500px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" alt="Blue Square">
    </div>
    <img width="100" height="100" class="smallimage_forslide1" id="smallimage" src="http://web.mit.edu/bzbarsky/www/testcases/css3-issues/blackSquare.png">
    <p class="text1" id="text1id">This is slide 1.</p>
    <p class="text2" id="text2id">This is slide 2.</p>
    <p class="text3" id="text2id">This is slide 3.</p>
    <img width="64" height="64" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg/512px-Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg.png" class="next" alt="Next" />
    <img width="64" height="64" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Circle_arrow_right_font_awesome.svg/512px-Circle_arrow_right_font_awesome.svg.png" class="prev" alt="Previous" />
</div>
```

Click on the **fiddle** to see it in action with css and javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/9xm2c9er/2/

As you can see, all of these elements are shown:
"This is slide 1.", "This is slide 2.", "This is slide 3.", and the small, black square image.

**How** can I hide "This is slide 1." and the black square image when I slide to "slideimage2", and vica verca with "slideimage1" and "slideimage3"?

I've been thinking about adding some sort of if statement within the "Next" and "Previous" javascript, but how can I detect when nth slide image is slided to?

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('.inner_wrapper img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.inner_wrapper');

    if($('.inner_wrapper img:eq(0)')) {
        $('#text1id').show();
        $('#smallimage').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#text1id').hide();
        $('#smallimage').hide();        
    }

 });
```

I believe the if statement I used here doesn't work, as it prevented the slider from appearing.

I appreciate all contributions - thanks a lot!

Edit: For clarification, I would like to mention that the slider has more than 2 images, and that I have several different tag elements that I would like to hide/show; **< p >** (text), **< a >** (links), and **< img >** (smaller images over slides).

1. I have already included a **basic image slider** in the fiddle that you can use that work with **images**, and any **absolute positioned elements** in it. However, in my fiddle, they will be visible on all the slides.
2. Based on the two **answers** I have currently received, they both can change **one type of elements for each individual slides** (in these answers, the p tags), by indexing a common class. They both work in a similar manner.
3. However, I have yet to choose a solution, as I still need to figure out how to do this with **several different elements for each slide**, in terms of number and types. For example, on the first slide, I can have 2 < a > links, and 4 < p > text tags, and 1 < button >, but on the second slide, I may have a different number of elements.

**Edit 2**: Here is a fiddle with the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/n0z6u07p/1/. By wrapping elements in divs, you can show/hide them depending on the image slided to in the slider.

Comment: Just passing by, your arrows are inverted and I don't think it is a good idea in a usability point of view.

Comment: @QuentinRoy Yeah, I know, it's not the one I actually use. I just use it for the fiddles and testing! But since you pointed it out, I'll correct it. > Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added data to your img tags :

```
<div class="outer_wrapper_hide" id="outer_wrapperID">
<div class="inner_wrapper" id="inner_wrapperID">
<img id="slideimage1" data-index="1" class="slideimage" height="500" width="500" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Svg_example_square.svg/500px-Svg_example_square.svg.png" alt="Green Square">
<img id="slideimage2" data-index="2" class="slideimage" height="500" width="500" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/500px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png" alt="Blue Square">
<img id="slideimage3" data-index="3" class="slideimage" height="500" width="500" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/500px-Red.svg.png" alt="Red Square">
</div>
<p class="label text1" id="text1id">This is slide 1.</p>
<p class="label text2" id="text2id" style="display: none;">This is slide 2.</p>
<p class="label text3" id="text3id" style="display: none;">This is slide 3.</p>
<img width="64" height="64" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg/512px-Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg.png" class="next" alt="Next" />
<img width="64" height="64" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Circle_arrow_right_font_awesome.svg/512px-Circle_arrow_right_font_awesome.svg.png" class="prev" alt="Previous" />
```

And I made a function to show/hide your labels :

```
    document.getElementById("outer_wrapperID").className = "outer_wrapper_show";
$('.inner_wrapper img:eq(0)').fadeIn(500);
$('#outer_wrapperID').fadeIn(500);

$('.inner_wrapper img:gt(0)').hide();

$('.next').click(function () {
   $('.inner_wrapper img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.inner_wrapper');
   toggleLabels();
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
  $('.inner_wrapper img:first-child').fadeOut();
  $('.inner_wrapper img:last-child').prependTo('.inner_wrapper').fadeOut();
  $('.inner_wrapper img:first-child').fadeIn();
  toggleLabels();
});

var toggleLabels = function () {
   $("p.label").hide(); 
   var firstIndex = $('.inner_wrapper img:first-child').data("index");
   $("p.text"+firstIndex).show();           
};
```

Comment: Hello, I tried adding " style="display: none;" to ".text2", and adding the toggleLabels into the fiddle, but text2 still won't show, and text1 won't hide. https://jsfiddle.net/8j0v1kcx/

Comment: dont forget data-index="1" and data-index="2"

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Thanks, it worked now (https://jsfiddle.net/8j0v1kcx/1/), but what if I have 3+ images? Any ideas to how to fit that with your code?

Comment: Ok, I tried to add another imageslide and p.text as well, but in this one, the text won't change. https://jsfiddle.net/8j0v1kcx/2/

Comment: Sorry, this one works (I've just edited my answer), just set a correct src for the third img

Comment: Thanks, it works now after adding label class to all the p tags. https://jsfiddle.net/8j0v1kcx/3/. But what about other tags, like < a > links, < button > and < img >? For the slides, I would like to have different element tags, and different numbers of elements for each slide. So for example, what if I just want to have 1 overlapping image on the first slide? https://jsfiddle.net/n0z6u07p/

Comment: You will have to find a clever way to show/hide everything easily. If you can wrap all of this (p, a, img, ...) of one category into a sing div, just show/hide this div. Or add one same class to every elements of a category and use a selector on this class to show/hide them.

Comment: Thanks, I think you found the solution I was looking for! I did as you said and put them into divs with class names "elements elemX" and it worked. https://jsfiddle.net/n0z6u07p/1/ Thank you for all the help through this sunday!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach I use for similar problems as yours: First hide **all** elements, then show the only needed (selected) one.

So the code should look like this:

HTML

```
...
<p class="text text1" id="text1id">This is slide 1.</p>
<p class="text text2" id="text2id">This is slide 2.</p>
...
```

JS:

```
...
var iText = 0;
var aTexts = $('p.text'), nTexts = aTexts.length;
function showText(i) {
    aTexts.hide().eq(i).show();
}
showText(0);
$('.next').click(function () {
    ...

    iText = (iText + 1) % nTexts;
    showText(iText);
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    ...

    iText = (iText - 1 + nTexts) % nTexts;
    showText(iText);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtqnLx0j/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but how could I implement that into the image slider?

Comment: I tried adding it in a fiddle with if statements, but I seem to have made a mistake somewhere: https://jsfiddle.net/mtqnLx0j/. Also, I assume that the "% 2" means an upper limit to the index? Then what about a lower limit? Also, this solution may not work for my image slider, as it can loop infinitely to both directions (ex: 5 clicks right = slide2, slide1, slide2, slide1, slide2 ...)

Comment: _I assume that the "% 2" means an upper limit to the index?_ No, it means [cyclic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Sorry, I had no idea how to code that. But this only works if the elements have the same tag and class, right? And perhaps needs to be text? I didn't specify it in the question, but I also have <a> and <img> tags that I'd like to hide/show as well. Any ideas on whether that can be included in your code?

Comment: _this only works if the elements have the same tag and class, right?_ No, this works for elements matching some jquery selector. **Any selector**, not only `'p.text'` as in this code. For instance, it might match elements having different tags, but the same class. This mean that you can show/hide different types of elements (texts, images etc) by the same code (selector). You only have to assign the same class to all needed elements.